# What is a full-fledged PowerShell command?

Tags: windows, powershell, command, powershell-cmdlet

If -let is a diminutive suffix and PowerShell commands are called command-lets, what is a full-fledged PowerShell command?

Comment: In PowerShell terminology "Command" is usually used as an umbrella-term for functions, cmdlets, scripts etc., rather than for a specific type. Cmdlets are not inferior in any sense, they are first-class functions if you will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'cmdlets' is used to compare PowerShell commandlets with with commands in traditional shells, rather than as a comparison to something else in PowerShell. e.g.:

> A cmdlet (pronounced "command-let") is a single-feature command that manipulates objects in Windows PowerShell. You can recognize cmdlets by their name format -- a verb and noun separated by a dash (-), such as Get-Help, Get-Process, and Start-Service.
>
> In traditional shells, the commands are executable programs that range from the very simple (such as attrib.exe) to the very complex (such as netsh.exe).
>
> In Windows PowerShell, most cmdlets are very simple, and they are designed to be used in combination with other cmdlets.

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648597(v=vs.85).aspx

and:

> A cmdlet is a lightweight command that is used in the Windows PowerShell environment. 
>   [..]
>   Cmdlets perform an action and typically return a Microsoft .NET Framework object to the next command in the pipeline.
>
> How Cmdlets Differ from Commands
>
> Cmdlets differ from commands in other command-shell environments in
>   the following ways:
>
> - Cmdlets are instances of .NET Framework classes;
>     they are not stand-alone executables.
> - Cmdlets can be created from as few as a dozen lines of code.
> - Cmdlets do not generally do their own parsing, error presentation, or
>     output formatting. Parsing, error presentation, and output formatting
>     are handled by the Windows PowerShell runtime.
> - Cmdlets process input objects from the pipeline rather than from
>     streams of text, and cmdlets typically deliver objects as output to
>     the pipeline.
> - Cmdlets are record-oriented because they process a single object at a
>     time.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714395(v=vs.85).aspx